# How can I get a certain number of characters in a row?

Tags: java

In a program I'm writing I want each row to print 10 characters if the user-inputted integer is above 10. When I run my code, the first line prints 11 numbers while the second line prints 9. How can I get both to print 10? Here's the code I'm using:
double s = 0;

```
    double s = 0;
    String str = "";

    double[] arr1 = new double[userInput];

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        arr1[i] = Math.random()*100;
    }  //Generates random array (size of array depends on user input)

    for (int i = 0; i<arr1.length;i++) {
        s = arr1[i];
        s = Math.round(s * 10.0) / 10.0;
        str += s + " ";
        if (i%10 == 0 && i!=0) {
            str += "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need more context for that code chunk. That might or might not be correct depending on what the surrounding code does.

Comment: I've added more code, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: There is still missing context still in my opinion. Where does the array come from? Where are you printing? Try posting all the (relevant) code which you are using.

Comment: Show the input, show the actual output, and show the desired output.

Comment: @Unknowin - Post an example of the expected output.

Comment: A proper [mre] would be something that I could copy from here and paste into my editor so that I could compile and see the code working (or the errors if it isn't). Your code isn't even a full method.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed in several ways:

1. Appending of the new line should be moved to the start of the loop

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0 && i !=0) {
        str += "\n";
    }

    s = arr1[i];
    s = Math.round(s * 10.0) / 10.0;
    str += s + " ";
}
```

---

2. Run the loop from 1 and fix the index by 1

Additionally, use of `StringBuilder` is preferable to concatenate multiple strings:

```java
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

for (int c = 1; c <= arr1.length; c++) {
    s = arr1[c - 1];
    s = Math.round(s * 10.0) / 10.0;
    str.append(s < 10? " " : "").append(s).append("  ");
    
    if (c % 10 == 0) {
        str.append('\n');
    }
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Test output for 42 elements:

```
58.3  52.2  48.9  41.4  78.3  58.9  93.2  44.8  66.3  75.5  
30.0  47.6  43.7  76.3   1.9  70.1  39.7  37.7  14.0   7.1  
41.8  31.8  84.9   2.2  72.7  42.5  48.8   5.8  95.0  83.0  
77.9  43.7  69.3  62.0  10.7  43.9  21.5  40.5  36.4  65.4  
 6.8  43.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i'm not misreading your question but this is a (somewhat simplefied version) of your code which does what i think you want.

You need to adapt this then to your specific needs but this is the basic requirement. If the user inputs a number grater than 10, 10 characters are printed for each line of the size of the array.

```
double userInput = 10;

//user input must be > 10 to continue
if (userInput < 10)
return;

//i explicitely defined my array for simplifications
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

//i go through each of the array positions
 for (int i = 0; i<arr1.length;i++) 
 {
   //for each position i print the first 10 items of the array in the same line
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      {
        System.out.print (arr1[j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println ("\n");
}
```

Output:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10